# malloc consolidate(): invalid chunk size

Tags: python, pyqt, gnuradio

When I close the PYQT5 application, it gives the error of

```
malloc consolidate(): invalid chunk size
Aborted (Core Dumped)
```

on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.
While the application is running, there was no problem. But when I clicked the close (X) button of application, the error occurs.

And sometimes it gives the another error which is

```
corrupted size  vs. prev_size
Aborted (Core Dumped)
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace? Run you program under gdb (`gdb --args /usr/bin/python my_program.py`) and then when it crashes execute the `bt` command and provide the full output. You can also try running it under valgrind (`valgrind --tool=memcheck /usr/bin/python my_program.py`)

Comment: This is probably due to using an outdated version of pyqt5 or qt5. What *specific* versions of those libraries are you using? Are they the official ubuntu packages, or were they installed via pip? If you can reproduce the problem using pyside2, that would suggest the problem is in qt5. (A backtrace probably won't be that useful, because it's unlikely that your libraries were compiled with the necessary debug symbols).